# Mail is sending from wpf application, but can not send from some pc

Tags: c#, .net, email

Mail is sending from wpf application, but can not send from some pc
When i run setup on my pc mail is sent properly but when i repeat this process from another pc mail is not sent and message is "Mail not Sent";

```
                SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
                smtp.Host = "mail.test.com";
                smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("test@test.com", "Test");
                string mailTo = emailId;
                string mailFrom = "test@test.com";
                string mailSub = subject;
                string mailMessage = strMessage;
                MailMessage message = new MailMessage(mailFrom, mailTo, mailSub, mailMessage);    

                message.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
                message.IsBodyHtml = true;

                try
                {
                    smtp.Send(message);
                    return "Send";
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
                    return "Failure";
                    //return ex.ToString();
                }
```

Comment: Is the SMTP server mail.test.com available from their PCs?

Comment: i used another mail which is working fine. i have changed this in the question.

Comment: did you face any exception? if it is, post that details too..

Comment: Can you provide the exception message and stack trace?

Comment: This exception come on client system, not on my system.
I think this exception of mail server issue.

Comment: Nothing WPF specific here, removing the tag...

Comment: please analyse the issue more and provide details.  eg credentials used to connect to smtp server. The response from smtp server (if reached). And exceptions etc.Also consider inner exceotions for more details.